# Como usar ping/pong em Websocket Java

Tags: java-ee, websocket

Procurei material na Web mais ainda não encontrei sobre como devo implementar as mensagens ping/pong no Servidor e Cliente, respectivamente.

Sei como enviar e receber, mas ainda não entendi a lógica disso tudo.
Alguém pode me ajudar nisso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você está pensando em implementar isso a nível de aplicação, dê uma olhada nesses [testes unitários do Tyrus](https://github.com/tyrus-project/tyrus/blob/master/tests/e2e/standard-config/src/test/java/org/glassfish/tyrus/test/standard_config/PingPongTest.java). A ideia é bem simples, crie a lógica de mensagens do lado de servidor:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/pingpong")
public static class PingPongEndpoint {

    private static final String PONG_RECEIVED = "PONG RECEIVED";

    @OnMessage
    public void onPong(PongMessage pongMessage, Session session) {
        try {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText(PONG_RECEIVED);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, String message) throws IOException {
        session.getBasicRemote().sendPing(null));
    }
}
```

O lado cliente envia pings (por exemplo, de tempos em tempos):

```
session.getBasicRemote().sendPing(null);
```

E verifica se o servidor enviou um pong:

```
session.addMessageHandler(new MessageHandler.Whole<PongMessage>() {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(PongMessage message) {
        System.out.println("### Client - received pong \"");
    }
});
```

Se o pong não chegou após um tempo sua conexão provavelmente foi interrompida. É recomendável tentar fechá-la e se reconectar.

Você também pode fazer o inverso, enviar pings do servidor para o cliente e esperar pongs; caso eles não cheguem pode fechar a conexão com o cliente. E é claro que o cliente pode estar em qualquer outra linguagem.

Você também não precisa ficar preso à `PongMessages` e `sendPing`, pode criar suas próprias mensagens (com `sendText`, `sendBinary`, `sendObject`, etc).

---

Se você gostaria a fazer isso puramente a nível de *Control Frames* e não se importa em consumir API não *standard*, dê uma olhada na classe [TyrusWebSocket](https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs/1.8.1/org/glassfish/tyrus/core/TyrusWebSocket.html) e nos métodos `onPing`, `onPong`, `sendPing` e `sendPong`, porém, não espere que todos os navegadores respondam corretamente aos pings com pongs, muito menos que eles mandem pings por conta própria para manter a conexão viva.

Comment: Então para verificar a inatividade da conexão "eu que devo implementar" isso com o ping/pong? Por exemplo, verificando o tempo de resposta (pong) do ping para remover ou não da lista de conexões ativas.

Comment: Luídne, exatamente. Control Frames com opscode já deveriam fazer isso automaticamente para você, mas, como disse, isso não é muito confiável (boa parte dos navegadores não manda os pings automaticamente, etc).